# Is it possible to return a response from a Web API constructor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API ApiController base class and I would like to perform some validations in the constructor. This might include checking the current load on the server. If it's high, I'd like to return an appropriate HttpResponseMessage indicating the requestor should try again later.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Your better of doing something like that in Application events. See the global.asax file, possibly using the `BeginRequest` event.

Comment: @mxmissile is right. If you're sure this is the path you want to head though, you should inherit the ApiController and create your own ApiController that all your controllers inherit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Haven't tested it but that's not what the constructor is for. I don't think all plumbing is set at that time.

You could use global filters for this purpose. [Here](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-web-api-controller-globally-without-having-to-use-authorize-attribute) you have a sample that sets a global filter for authorization, you should use a similar logic but creating your own filter for your specific purposes.

A global filter would intercept all your requests and is executed before the controller actions so is a good place to perform your task.

Comment: Thanks for all the good ideas. I'm already using some ActionFilterAttributes, so I think I will go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Even though what you are doing sounds like it may be better to revise the approach. Note that you can throw `HttpResponseException` since the `WebApi` is Rest Service  `HttpResponseException` is the recommended way to throw Exceptions back to the client.

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
   Content = new StringContent("No idea what happened "),
   ReasonPhrase = "Something was not Not Found"
}
throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using .NET 4.5, then you'd be better off creating a custom MessageHandler. You'll need to extend [DelegatingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx) in order to do that.

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler {
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpMessageRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        // Access the request object, and do your checking in here for things
        // that might cause you to want to return a status before getting to your 
        // Action method.

        // For example...
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

Then inside your `WebApiConfig`, just add the following code to use the new Handler:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't throw HttpResponseException in constructor, that will always cause 500.

Easiest way is to override ExecuteAsync():

```
public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        if (!myAuthLogicCheck()) {
            // Return 401 not authorized
            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "User not logged in" };
            throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
        }

        return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
}
```