# ASP.Net Core Web API application : How to return success from all my action methods and not run the code in a certain mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am configuring my server in various modes and I am setting the modes of the application from a config file. 
So, say if I run my HTTP server is in mode "X", I want clients to get "HTTP STATUS 200 and don't execute any logic" if they hit a valid endpoint.
and if the server is in mode "Y" all endpoints should perform the logic and return the status as per the request processing

```
[Route("api/todo")]
public class TodoController : Controller{

        //if in mode "Y"
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var item = _todoRepository.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

       //if in mode "X"
       [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
       public IActionResult GetById(long id){
         return Ok();
       }

}
```

Is there a way using filter that can return OK to the client without getting inside of the action method?

EDIT:
When i say modes, I mean like modes like "production", "testing", "staging".
[like we have different db connection strings for all these modes]
So, I have a mode called "X" [and if my server is running on mode "X"], any client who hits the endpoints exposed by me will get success.

Comment: Can you be much clear on what do you mean by modes?

Comment: When i say modes, I mean like modes like "production", "testing", "staging".
[like we have different db connection strings for all these modes]
So, I have a mode called "X" [and if my server is running on mode "X"], any client who hits the endpoints exposed by me will get success.

Comment: Where are you configuring it?

Comment: I will be reading a variable from the config file, which will tell me the  current mode.
Something like: 
string mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[mode];

Comment: Can't you access your config from your controller?

Comment: I can access it from my controller. But I don't want to put if else inside the controller logic. Because that's not the logic part of the action method. If you intend to say this.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292907/is-it-possible-to-return-a-response-from-a-web-api-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using a validation [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware). I don't get exactly what you mean by running the HTTP server in mode X or mode Y, so you need to adapt your code.

For example, take a look at the picture below:

[image]

You'll need to implement something like the "Authorization middleware" in the picture. You just need to return the request with HTTP 200 OK before if gets on the controllers (app.UseMvc() in the Startup.cs).

Comment: I am trying doing it using middleware, will get back in case of a doubt.